# MS ACCESS OpenRecordset rounding decimals

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export, recordset

I have a query that is showing the price for my products and comparing with previous months. The query within Access is showing the prices correctly with 4 decimal places but when I export to Excel with code below the numbers are rounded to 2 decimal places.
My code has many formatting lines that I omitted. Please note that I am not formatting the price in the excel. I want to show the entire number.
I think the Recordset function is somehow rounding the number.
I appreciate the help. Thank you

```
            Dim xlApp As Object
            Dim xlBook As Object
            Dim xlSheet As Object
            Dim i As Integer

            Dim SQL As String
            Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

 SQL = "SELECT tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.ID, tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.[Raw Material]," & _
        "tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.Lastbought, tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.PreviousPrice," & _
        "tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.Newdate, tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.LastPrice," & _
        "tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.ReportDate FROM tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice ORDER BY tblTempCurrentPastRawPrice.[Raw Material]"


        Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)


 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            xlApp.Visible = False
            Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
            Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

    With xlSheet

   i = 7    

            Do While Not rs1.EOF


                .Range("A" & i).Value = Nz(rs1![Raw Material], "")
                .Range("B" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Lastbought, "")
                .Range("C" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!PreviousPrice, 0)
                .Range("D" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Newdate, 0)
                .Range("E" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!LastPrice, 0)

                i = i + 1
                rs1.MoveNext
```

Comment: If you edit the Excel cell, are the decimals still missing?

Comment: yes. the excel file comes with 2 decimals. in Access is showing 0.3193 if I change format in excel it will be 0.3200

Comment: Do you change the format in Excel before or after the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I can reproduce this. It happens because the columns are of type `Currency`.

Apparently, Excel as usual wants to be more clever than is good for you, and assumes that Currency always comes with two decimals and rounds to that.

To easily reproduce, use this code:

```
With xlSheet
    i = 7
    .Range("F" & i).Value = CDbl(1.2345)    ' Result: 1.2345
    .Range("G" & i).Value = CCur(1.2345)    ' Result: 1.23 €
End With
```

Note that `CCur(1.2345)` in Access is still `1.2345`.

To solve it, convert to `Double` before writing to Excel, and afterwards **format** as Currency in Excel (with 2 or 4 decimals, in both cases the number will actually have all 4 decimals):

```
        With .Range("C" & i)
            .Value = CDbl(Nz(rs1!PreviousPrice, 0))
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000 $"
        End With
```